# SQLite Autoincrement Based on Another Column's Value

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I basically want to create a table like this

```
col1|col2
---------
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    1
3    1
2    2
1    4
```

where column 2 autoincrements, but its autoincrement values are not tied to the overall table but column 1's value. Is this possible?

Comment: @BillKarwin I'm not sure this can easily be done in SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I found a duplicate question, but it was for PostgreSQL. Apologies for temporarily marking your question as a duplicate. I've reversed that.

I don't know for certain if this is possible in SQLite in an automated way, but one solution would be to do it in steps:

1. `BEGIN` a transaction and `INSERT` one row the table with a NULL for the col2. This should acquire a RESERVED lock and prevent other concurrent processes from doing the same thing and causing a race condition.
2. `SELECT MAX(col2) FROM mytable WHERE col1 = ?` to get the greatest value inserted for the given group so far.
3. `UPDATE mytable SET col2 = ?+1 WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 IS NULL` Using the MAX discovered in step 2.
4. `COMMIT` to write the changes to the file.

Comment: [BEGIN](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) IMMEDIATE or BEGIN EXCLUSIVE already takes a lock.